# Multiple Supervisor Not Visible on Storm UI

Tags: centos, apache-zookeeper, apache-storm, nimbus

We are trying to set up apache storm multi node cluster using 4 machines .
Below are their config files as we use them currently:

```
a) Zookeeper Server : 10.135.155.133(running on windows 7)
b) Nimbus Host : 10.135.158.22 (running on centos)
c) Supervisor1 : 10.135.156.63 (running on centos)
d) Supervisor2 : 10.135.156.162 (running on centos)
```

On zookeeper server running on windows we have following configuration for zoo.cfg

```
tickTime=2000
initLimit=10
syncLimit=5
dataDir=d:\\tmp\\zookeeper
clientPort=2181
```

On nimbus host we have following storm.yaml configuration:

```
storm.zookeeper.servers:
 - "10.135.155.133"
nimbus.host: "nimbus1"
storm.local.dir: "/storm/apache-storm-1.1.0/lib/"
storm.zookeeper.port: 2181
```

nimbus1=10.135.158.22

On Supervisor 1 and Supervisor 2 we have following storm.yaml

```
 storm.zookeeper.servers:
 - "10.135.155.133"
 nimbus.host: "nimbus1"
 storm.local.dir: "/storm/apache-storm-1.1.0/lib/"
 supervisor.slots.ports:
 - 6704
 - 6705
 - 6706
 - 6707
```

Now the problem is when we are running zookeeper ,nimbus host ,supervisor 1 and supervisor 2 .
We get only one of the supervisor on storm ui at a time when we refresh the storm ui we get both the supervisor alternatingly but only one is displayed  at a time . They both have name localhost.
How can I get both the supervisor on storm ui at the same time .
What additional configurations can be done to achieve both the supervisor on the storm ui ?

Comment: Could you share any errors found in the supervisor log or ui log of storm ?